# Create videos with react native and generate uri to share or save on device

Tags: android, ios, react-native, replaykit, android-mediaprojection

I have a  component that renders a short animation, with a maximum duration of 8s, I need to generate a video of this component and get a uri, so the user can share it or save it on the device. It doesn't seem like anything in react native supports something like this, I'm open to native implementations for both platforms.

Any ideias?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A simple option is recording that component region  while video is playing if that not hurt UX - https://github.com/yutasuzuki/react-native-record-screen-zone

Comment: Are you sure that this library works properly on iOS?